# How to execute file with multiple DDL statements

Tags: amazon-redshift, connector

I'm running redshift_connector in Python under the Window environment.  I have .sql file that is the collection of DDLs for the database.

when I execute I get the following error
'cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement'

Answer (score 0):

You've probably found a solution for this already, but for the sake of closing the loop, here is mine:

I switched from using redshift_connector to using psycopg2, which does allow multiple commands.
If you need to use redshift_connector, however, there is a little workaround. It might mean updating some of your sql code:

Add a function to your python script which splits the sql into multiple commands, delimited by the ';' character, for example.

The only issue with this is where you need the ';' to mean ';'. For this reason, I added an escape argument, which is where you'd need to update your sql. This allows you to replace the ';' in the sql which the function then replaces with a ';' after it has split out the multiple commands.

Here's the function:

def rc_multicommand(rc_cursor,cs,escape=None):
    cs_split = cs.split(";")
    for split_command in cs_split:
        if not len(split_command) == 0:
            if not escape == None:
                split_command = split_command.replace(escape,';')
            rc_cursor.execute(split_command)